# Selecting specific textbox to focus for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, textbox

I am trying to empty the textbox when selected. I have multiple textboxes. How do i select the specific textbox dynamically? Below is my code:

```
private void newToDoTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the text box when it gets focus.

        newToDoTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
        newToDoTextBox2.Text = String.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'select the specific textbox dynamically'? do you want to use newToDoTextBox_GotFocus common with the two controls selected action?

Comment: For an example I would want to click on the textbox1 and clear the textbox1. It works but textbox2 also clears when I don't click it

Comment: Hi, read my answer please.

Comment: Saw it, will test it out in a while because I am still out for lunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method please:

```
// use this method to your 2 textbox
private void yourTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I will do it as soon as possible as I am out at the moment. Thanks

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help. you get the object refer it as textbox and converted it to text. Now it make sense. I didnt know that the object sender can be use in this way. Learned new things again thanks!